# Removing liquid lipstick from clothes?

Tags: cleaning

A bottle of liquid lipstick has found it's way in the dryer, and now all our clothes have spots of red on them.

What is a good way to remove them?

Here's the bottle:

[image: Lipstick bottle]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the lip gloss is probably oil based, try rubbing a spot or two in an inconspicuous are with an oily stain remover such as [Lestoil](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Lestoil-Heavy-Duty-Multi-Purpose-Cleaner-48-fl-oz/23619936) or liquid
dish-washing detergent. However, since it is also a pigment-based colorant, i.e. contains opaque particles, rather than just a soluble dye, a *lot* of scrubbing using a toothbrush will be needed to remove adhered particles. Simply putting the garments in a solvent will not be enough.

Note that rubbing may raise the nap or otherwise damage the clothes, so test on one spot on each garment.

Comment: With dishsoap and a good rubbing, this seems to be working pretty well.